# Google Script - Copy Data from one Workbook To Another - importrange() Alternative

Tags: google-apps-script

Recently, I have been seeing more and more failures of importrange() on various workbooks so i am toying with the idea of setting up a script to copy data from one sheet to another and put the script on a timer.  The trouble is, even though its not a lot of data, it still exceeds the maximum execution time.  Any thoughts on how i can resolve this (Besides making the range smaller and processing smaller chunks of data)?  Here is my code:

```
function CopyData() {
//Clear DataSheet
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('12ZS...').getSheetByName('DataSheet').getRange('A:C').clearContent();

//Copy new database data
  var SData = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1cnNN...').getSheetByName('QuoteCounts').getRange('M1:O5000').getValues();
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('12ZS...').getSheetByName('DataSheet').getRange('A1:C5000').setValues(SData);
}
```

Comment: Show execution transcript.

Comment: There are none.  The status is "Timed Out", "No logs are available for this execution"

Comment: How many rows are in your quote counts sheet(filled and empty)?

Comment: @PY_ Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, when Sheets API is used for your situation, what result will you get? And if you can provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue, we can check and think of the solution. Even if you cannot do it, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function CopyData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('12ZS...')
  ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet').getRange('A:C').clearContent();
  var SData = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1cnNN...').getSheetByName('QuoteCounts').getRange('M1:O5000').getValues();
  ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet').getRange(1,1,SData.length,SData[0].length).setValues(SData);
}
```

You could also do it this way:

```
function CopyData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('12ZS...')
  ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet').getRange('A:C').clearContent();
  var sdrg=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1cnNN...').getSheetByName('QuoteCounts').getRange('M1:O5000');
  var SData =sdrg.getValues();
  ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet').getRange(1,1,sdrg.getHeight(),sdrg.getWidth()).setValues(SData);
}
```

Comment: Both of those timed out as well.

Comment: Take a look at executions.

Comment: No logs are available for this execution.   Status:  Timed Out

Comment: How about execution transcript?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to view that

Comment: View menu top choice.

Comment: All have 0 seconds but this one:
[19-06-05 09:58:42:656 PDT] Range.getValues() [373.264 seconds]
[19-06-05 09:58:43:139 PDT] Execution failed: Exceeded maximum execution time [373.509 seconds total runtime]

Comment: That's 15000 values so how about trying to break it up into three columns.  I don't know if there is a hard limit there

Comment: I tried that as well and it still fails even at 1 column @ 3K rows.